# C modify global char array

Tags: c

i have problem in C.
I want in function1 update/modify a global string (char array)

how can i update my variable dest and share with main function ?

edit:
i found solution

```
char *alphabet;

int function1(char* newstring) {


    alphabet = (char*)malloc(63);

    printf ("%s\n", alphabet);


    strcpy(alphabet, newstring);

    return 0;
}

int main() {
   char* test="newstring";
   function1(test);

   printf ("%s\n", alphabet);

    return 0;
```

Comment: infinite loop..

Comment: and `dest` is not initialized.

Comment: you need a C book.

Comment: `char dest[];` does not have any size. It is a tentative definition.

Comment: So many issues...

Comment: Is it a tentative definition or incomplete type?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin my compiler gave no warning (about the definition), and when I follow it with `char dest[20];` that too is acccepted.

Comment: `GCC` will complain all the errors and warnings if you go through one by one its easier for you to understand what is the problem. Why while loop is not executing as you wanted? You need to use `#include <string.h>` to use `strcpy`.

Comment: @rori ... two infinite loops. Can you figure out why?

Comment: When I compile this with -Wall and -Wextra I get 7 warnings. Read them.

Comment: @WeatherVane, thanks. When I see one of those wonky global things that are incomplete, I haven't a good handle on whether they are just forward declarations or one that would be flagged as an error as an incomplete type. (I'll just have to set some time aside and work with them a bit to have it sink in)

Answer (score 3):

Let us see what `gcc` has to say about your code:

```
gcc -Wall test.c -o test

test.c: In function ‘function1’:
test.c:8:25: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
     while (newstring[i] != NULL) {
                         ^~
test.c:9:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strcpy’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       strcpy(dest, newstring[i]);
       ^~~~~~
test.c:9:7: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
test.c:9:7: note: include ‘<string.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘strcpy’
test.c:9:20: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
       strcpy(dest, newstring[i]);
                    ^~~~~~~~~
test.c:9:20: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:19:20: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
     while (dest[i] != NULL) {
                    ^~
test.c:20:22: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
       printf ("[%d] %s\n", i, dest[i]);
                      ^
test.c: At top level:
test.c:3:6: warning: array ‘dest’ assumed to have one element
 char dest[];
      ^~~~
```

As you can see there are so many warnings to take care of.

> **Take warnings seriously and fix them**.

Doing that the code could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char dest[32];

int function1(char* newstring) {
    // Or simply use strcpy instead of a loop... 
    int i = 0;
    while(newstring[i] != '\0')
    {
      dest[i] = newstring[i];
      ++i;
    }
    dest[i] = '\0';
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char* test="newstring";
    function1(test);
    int i = 0;
    while (dest[i] != '\0') {
      printf ("[%d] %c\n", i, dest[i]);
      ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[0] n
[1] e
[2] w
[3] s
[4] t
[5] r
[6] i
[7] n
[8] g
```

**note** You should also check for buffer overflow, i.e. that `i` is always less than 32. For clarity I omitted that but make sure to add that before the code is considered done..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use loop to copy strings using strcpy.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

char dest[50];

int main()
{
    char* test = "newstring";
    strcpy(dest, test);
    int i = 0;
    while(dest[i] != '\0')
    {
       printf("%d: %c\n",i, dest[i]);
       i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have made solution for your code to work.

```
char dest[];
```

This statement gives warning: array 'dest' assumed to have one element.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char dest[];

int function1(char* newstring)
{
    int i = 0;
    char temp[50];
    while (newstring[i]) {
        temp[i]=newstring[i];
        i++;
    }
    strcpy(dest, temp);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char* test="newstring";
    function1(test);
    int i = 0;
    while (dest[i]) {
      printf ("[%d] %c\n", i, dest[i]);
      i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[0] n
[1] e
[2] w
[3] s
[4] t
[5] r
[6] i
[7] n
[8] g
```

Comment: Not to be rude but this code is wrong. It has undefined behavior for multiple reasons, e.g. the `strcpy`

Comment: Yes but I only tried to make your code working.

Comment: I guess mean: "make OPs code work", i.e. the code in the question... Anyway - you didn't succeed as your code isn't correct either. 1) `char dest[];` -> `char dest[50];` 2) Make sure to zero-terminate `temp`

Comment: Yes you are correct. I only tried to make @rori code working. Maybe my code isn't correct but it provide output with little warning.